# Combine PHP foreach with if statement

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a PHP foreach loop. After every iteration but the last a comma "," should be displayed. This in itself isn't an issue but for the fact that I also have an "if" statement inside my foreach loop.

For example:

```
$array = Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 41 [1] => Business 1 [2] => 37) [1] => Array ( [0] => 42 [1] => Business 2 [2] => 36));

foreach($array as $index => $item) {
    if ($item[2] == 37){
        $data = $item[1];
        if ($item !== end($array)) $data .= ',';
        echo $data;
    }
}
```

This is a much slimmed down version of my actual code but the basics are the same.

My problem is that the comma is being inserted even if the iteration is the last displayed because the foreach loop counts all of the items not just the ones that apply to the "if" statement.

I am terrible at explaining these things so please ask me to clarify anything if you need me to.

Basically, how can I make sure that the last comma is not applied?

Comment: @ceejayoz provided the most elegant solution, imho. If for some reason you cannot or don't want to use it, trim the trailing comma after the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Construct an array in the `foreach`, then `implode` it outside the loop with `,` as the delineator.

Answer (score 1):

A way to do it would be to use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```
$array = Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 41 [1] => Business 1 [2] => 37) [1] => Array ( [0] => 42 [1] => Business 2 [2] => 36));

$finishedItems = array();
foreach($array as $index => $item) {
    if ($item[2] == 37){
        finishedItems[] = $item[1];
    }
}
echo implode(',',finishedItems);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the comma all the time and remove the last comma after the foreach, with the substr funcion from 1 to lenght-1